# jquery :checked with display:none

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the checked radio buttons in the page, and it works until I put the style="display:none;" attribute (I'm putting this attribute for design reasons - replacing the default radio button).
 Is there another way to selected the checked radio buttons the checked attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to work just fine.. http://www.jsfiddle.net/XcpCW/

The problem must lie with the plug-in you use (to replace the default radio buttons) that handles the radio buttons in the background..

If the plugin updates the hidden radio buttons as it should then

```
$(':radio:checked')
```

will return all checked radio buttons..